# Using List.nth on an 'a list list in SML

Tags: list, sml

I'm trying to declare a function takelist : 'a list list -> int -> 'a list, so that calling takelist xs n will return the elements in spot number n in the lists from xs.

```
takelist [[#"3", #"6"], [#"6", #"2"], [#"5", #"9"]] 1;
```

should return [#"6", #"2", #"9"].

This is what I have:

```
fun tagliste (x::xs) n = List.nth(x,n);
```

I does half of what I want, and I can't figure how to get everything. I'm just getting the n from the first list instead of all of them. I've been told that map will be able to help, but so far I haven't had any luck using it correctly.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` takes a function `f` and a list `[x0, x1, ..., xn]` and returns `[f x0, f x1, ..., f xn]`.

So if we define `f x` to be `List.nth(x,n)`, you get back `[List.nth (x0, n), List.nth (x1, n), ..., List.nth (xn, n)]`, which is exactly what you want.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you mean.

Comment: @George: I mean `fun tagliste xs n = map (fn x => List.nth (x,n)) xs`